# How to get local users with Active Directory C++

Tags: c++, active-directory, ldap, root, windows-users

I need to get users' accounts on a computer. Trying to use Active Directory, here an example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676882(v=vs.85).aspx

But I've got hr = ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN here

```
HRESULT hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://rootDSE",
                       NULL,
                       NULL,
                       ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, // Use Secure Authentication.
                       IID_IADs,
                       (void**)&pObject);
```

What should I tune?

Comment: If the user account is not in a domain, only NameSamCompatible is supported.